# Java Date and time

Tags: javascript, calendar, weekday

Hey guys im trying to find some info regarding java and the calendar class. I need to write an if statement that says if it is a weekend i.e sat or sunday then do this else do this

Cheers

Thanks for the help however i don't think im implementing it correctly, nothing is being displayed now.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 function recalculate() {
    var sum = 49;
    int day = Calendar.getInstance().get( Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK );

    if ( day == Calendar.SATURDAY || day == Calendar.SUNDAY ){
    sum = 80;
    }
    $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
        sum =  parseInt($(this).attr("rel"));

    });

    $("#output").html(sum);
 }

 $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
    recalculate();
 });

});
```

Comment: Does the if statement require that you have fun, fun, fun, fun when true?

Comment: You know that your code is **JavaScript** not Java, don't you?

Comment: hahah after i posted this i realised. Im new to java and assumed they were the same thing

Comment: @Simon: well you mean javascript again, don't you (*Im new to java*)?

Comment: sorry im new to javaSCRIPT lol, i've got to get use to adding the extra

Comment: This question (and its answers) don't make much sense any more ...

Answer (score 1):

It's all in here:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html

```
int day = Calendar.getInstance().get( Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK );

if ( day == Calendar.SATURDAY || day == Calendar.SUNDAY ){
   // fun fun fun fun fun
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)== Calendar.SATURDAY ||cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)==Calendar.SUNDAY){
    //hurray..weekend..!
}else{

}
```

**See Also**

- [API Documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#DAY_OF_WEEK)

Comment: Considering sat & sun as weekend

Answer (score 0):

```
Calendar cld = Calendar.getInstance();
if (cld.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SATURDAY) {
// it's saturday
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Simone The code you have there does not look anything like Java - infact, it's more like JavaScript in JQuery format.  Anyway, @Matthew and @Jigar have provided you with sample code.

If that does not help, them make sure to tag your question as Javascript next time so that people with that experience can help answer your question.

Good luck